# asp.net adds # end of the url after postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple web form and there is a button.
After clicking the button it automatically adds "#" end of the url.

Let's say the url is:
http://www.domain.com/test.aspx

after postback it changes to
http://www.domain.com/test.aspx#

I'm using url rewriter module of UrlRewriter.NET, maybe it is related with this.

But before postback the form tag is as following:

```
<form method="post" action="#"
```

Thanks for any idea.

Edit: I'm using master page so cannot remove action tag manually.

Comment: so remove the `action="#"` ?

Comment: and the fact you have an hashtag in your `action` attribute doesn't give you an hint ?

Comment: I'm using master pages so cannot remove action tag easily.

Comment: show the code you're using to generate the form tag in your master page. I've never seen a hash added in a form generated in a masterpage

Comment: well thanks Anthony there is an Action="#" tag on form, but removing it caused several  url rewriting problem, I'll try to find what's going on behind

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the action attribute. The form will then automatically post to the current page. The Url-rewrite module is not necesairy for this scenario.

**Edit**

Because you can't delete it because of masterpages, you can delete the attribute quick and dirty using javascript. If you're using jQuery, you can use a variation of this code:

```
$('form').removeAttr('action')
```

Comment: it is adding automatically because of the master page

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
For url rewriting module works fine form action attribute should be set on master page.
And Url rewriting module changes the action tag and I don't why but adds # character at the end of the action tag.

I used javascript to remove it, on master page.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function OnLoaded() {
        //alert(document.forms[0].action);
        var s = document.forms[0].action;
        if (s.length >= 1 && s[s.length - 1] == '#') {
            document.forms[0].action = s.substr(0, s.length - 1);
            //alert(document.forms[0].action);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="OnLoaded();">
```

Hope helps someone face the same problem.